# How to get the type of a web part (with JavaScript)?

Tags: 2013, web-part, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to determine the **type of a web part** (eg. Script Editor, Search Results, etc.) on pages using JavaScript.

I started with REST and succeeded in getting the web part manager for a page and got the web part definitions (`SP.WebParts.WebPartDefinition`) as well. Unfortunately there is no type information, only `Title`, `TitleUrl`, `ZoneIndex`, `Id` etc. There is also no `Properties` property which I saw in some samples.

My request looks like this:

```
https://siteUrl/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl)/getLimitedWebPartManager(scope=1)/webparts?$expand=Webpart
```

I'm interested in SharePoint 2013 and 2016. I read about an `ExportWebpart` API which was introduced in 2016 for SP Online which seems to be missing at least on my on-prem test farm. If there are any means for on-prem I'd also like to know any patch level needed for the API to be available. But I could probably google this myself once I know the API.

So how do I get the type of a web part using JavaScript and REST (or JSOM - maybe there are more possibilities?) for SP on-prem?

---

**More information**

When exporting the web part manually in the browser UI I get the information I need - in two places of the exported web part XML:

Metadata of the exported web part (**This is what I'd like to have!**):

```
<metaData>
  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ClientWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
```

As an alternative (**workaround**) the properties would be (maybe) sufficient for my case as well. I could identify the web parts I'm interested in via their unique combination of properties like the FeatureId and others:

```
    <property name="FeatureId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">GUID I can use</property>
```

But I just cannot get these properties as well, using REST.

I checked that the export mode allows exporting the data:

[image]

That the web part properties are retrievable via Remote API:

[image]

I tried expanding `WebPart.Properties` instead of `WebPart` (like in some JSOM samples).

Nope. Maybe it's just not possible via REST? The documentation is no reason to party either.

Comment: Have you try "?contents=1" it will show you the web part types on the page

Answer (score 1):

I found a JS object called webpart properties... As alwas at JSON it's very "well" documented:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246541.aspx

Maybe the webpart type is hidden somewhere there...
I haven't found it at the first glance, but here is the code, maybe a starting point:

```
var ctxOBJ = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var webOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_web();
var siteOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_site();
var pageURL = window.location.pathname;
var webPartManagerOBJ = webOBJ.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageURL).getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartsOBJ = webPartManagerOBJ.get_webParts();
ctxOBJ.load(webPartsOBJ);
ctxOBJ.executeQueryAsync();

var webPartOBJ = webPartsOBJ.getById(0).get_webPart()
ctxOBJ.load(webPartOBJ);
ctxOBJ.executeQueryAsync(); 

var propsOBJ = webPartOBJ.get_properties()
ctxOBJ.load(propsOBJ);
ctxOBJ.executeQueryAsync();
```

Comment: Seems like the properties are only retrievable via JSOM. :-/ I could try identifying web parts by their set of properties. But only the type would be unique. Let's see if somebody knows something. Otherwise I have to go for JSOM+property poking. // A note about the code: this PoC is prone to timing issues and might fail. Copy-and-pasters beware ^^